# Distributions of Product of Random Variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X,Y \geq 0$ be independent with distribution functions $F$ and $G$. Find the distribution function of $XY$.

Let $Z = XY$. Then we must find $P(Z \leq z)$. 
Well, $P(Z \leq z ) = P(XY \leq z) = P(Y \leq \frac{z}{X})$, but that's pretty much where I get stuck. I could proceed if the functions had densities, but I don't think they necessarily do.

I assume there's some trick to rewrite $P(Y \leq \frac{z}{X})$, but no idea what it is.

Comment: I think the question is meant for you to arrive at an integral expression and just leave it at that.

Comment: So.. just integrate the distributions?

Comment: I would guess that if it's an exercise, then the task is to go from 2-dim integral to 1-dim, and that's it. If you're interested, besides the plain simple integral, there are many equivalent ways in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution), but you should know there's no "general formula" (in the elementary sense) for the distribution of products.

Comment: Hmm thanks. I looked at the Wiki, but all the derivations still use densities, so that's kind of disappointing. Which "plain simple" integral were you thinking of exactly? If there's no "general formula" I don't feel so bad lol.

Comment: There's no need for densities. Fubini's theorem shows that $$P(XY\leq t)=  \int F_X(\frac ty) dP_Y(y) =  \int F_Y(\frac tx) dP_X(x)$$

Comment: Are $F_X$ and $F_Y$ the distribution functions for $X$ and $Y$ in your case @GabrielRomon?