# Probability distribution function for $Z=XY$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Currently, I am reading Probability Theory and Example from Durret.

Here is the question 2.1.14 from the 5th edition.

> Let $X,Y\geq 0$ be independent with distribution functions $F,G$, find the distribution function for $XY$.

Here, the question hasn't assume that $F,G$ are absolute continuous. The hint I found online was to apply the natural logarithm to $XY$, and then we have 
\begin{align*}
\ln(XY)=\ln(X)+\ln(Y)
\end{align*}
and use the convolution to find the distribution. My question is how can we deal with the case $X=0$ or $Y=0$? The domain for a distribution function has to be $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Is there any kind of rigorous argument about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546709/distributions-of-product-of-random-variables